# How do I share a script that uses the Google API?

Tags: python, google-api, google-oauth

I just made a pretty simple python script at work and I need to share it with my coworkers. The problem is the script makes use of the Google API to make changes to a spreadsheet. Is there a simple way to share my credentials with anyone that runs the script?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Google APIS (generally) need a valid token. Just share your token with your colleagues or ask them to create a new one.

Comment: Would the token you're refering to be credentials.json? So I can just copy it and it will work just fine on any computer?

Comment: Yes, it also depends upon how you're accessing the credentials for the script. One of the options is loading service account details via default named credentials.json